# Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History' in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser

I am working with an HTML website template I got a couple of months ago. I was creating a site and everything worked fine. Came back later to do some changes and now when I open my index.html file it only loads navbar, bottom and side borders.

The exact error is:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History':
>   A history state object with URL *index url* cannot be created in a
>   document with origin 'null'.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Look at this http://twinery.org/forum/discussion/4747/uncaught-securityerror-failed-to-execute-replacestate-on-history it will provide you answers.

Answer (score 1):

> Chromium made changes with v45 that broke all uses of the HTML5
>   History API in files when opened via the file://.
>
> Try to run your app in a webserver.